# Error found when loading /etc/profile/

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

When I turn on my laptop(Ubuntu 14.04),appears

```
Error found when loading /etc/profile:\n\n/etc/profile.d/myenv_vars.sh:line
```

`LD command not found`

What should I do? Can I delete profile.d?

Comment: The "\n\n" could be the result of a badly expanding macto. (even *before* /etc/profile.d/... is included)

Comment: @wildplasser
How to solve this,how to delete macro?

Comment: What are the contents of /etc/profile.d/myenv_vars.sh ?

Comment: Why are you adding user files to the /etc/profile.d directory?

Comment: @glennjackman
LD LIBRARY PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD LIBRARY PATH

Comment: That should be `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with underscores, not spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file should have

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

"space" is not a valid character for shell variable names.

To avoid the trailing colon:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

If LD_LIBRARY_PATH is null or unset, the new value will be just "/usr/local/lib"
If LD_LIBRAY_PATH has a value, the new value will be "/usr/local/lib:old_value"

Comment: If `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not already set, this will set it to `/usr/local/lib:`. If I'm not mistaken, the empty component after the trailing `:` means it searches the current directory, equivalent to `/usr/local/lib:.`. That might not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If the first line of the file contains:
     #!/bin/sh
but the file has cr/lf line endings, you will get this error.  Do this:
    # dos2unix /etc/profile.d/env_vars.sh
and try logging in again:
    $ exec ${SHELL} -l
Should be no errors.